# Create new package in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've just moved from years of using Eclipse to the brave new world of IntelliJ and I'm trying to iron out the little (trivial) little things that are slowing me down.

The latest is hopefully painfully obvious when you know how to do it.

I create a new package under my source folder:

```
uk.ac.cam.admin
```

I right click on this new package to create another sub-package:

```
uk.ac.cam.admin.domain
```

All well so far, now I want to create a package of `service` at the same level as `domain`.
However creating it from `uk.ac.cam.admin.domain` quite rightly results in `uk.ac.cam.admin.domain.service` and creating it on the source just results in `service`.

Obviously I can create a new package from the source and type the fully qualified path, but it's 2013 and I'm lazy!  ;)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Disable **Compact Empty Middle Packages** option in the `Project View`:

[image: compact]

You will now see `admin` as a separate node and will be able to create a new package inside it.

Comment: doesn't solve the issue with current version of IDEA, refer to below answer from Tharaka

Comment: @vikramvi please clarify the problem, it works the same in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.x.

Answer (score 52):

You can follow these steps:

1. Select the package from Project Pane
2. Double click the relevant section from the breadcrumb. Then it will get selected.
3. Right click on the same item
4. Select "New" → "Package" from the menu

   [image]

Comment: I like this one better. Otherwise I'd end up changing the "compact empty middle packages" just to create a package to then switch the config back.

Comment: I also prefer this one. It is even better if you avoid using mouse. Provided you already are editing a file in one of subpackages. Step 1 can then be avoided and steps 2-4 can be done as the following (on MacOS, though, I suppose it should be similar for Win/Linux):
2) Cmd+Up to enter the navigation breadcrumb and use arrows if necessary to highlight the target package
3) Ctrl+Enter summons the "New" submenu directly without the need to go through the more general right-click menu
4) Start typing "package" to filter out the menu item you need and/or navigate with arrow down to it.

Comment: This should have been accepted answer. Not sure why IDEA has such a bad UX and design compared to Eclipse, I really miss Eclipse in these things

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 46):

Follow these steps:

1. First set the folder as a "Sources Root" by right clicking and navigating to "Mark directory".
2. Right click on the same item
3. Select "New" → "Package"

In my case, I was not able to see the create new package option.

Comment: Before I performed this first step, there was no option to create a new package anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To create package the Folder/Directory should be marked as Source or Test.
Right click project->Project Structure->Project settings->Modules->select the folder where you want to create package and mark its as either Source or Test by clicking the respective colored icons. Then apply and ok.
Now you will see the Folder either in blue(Source) or green(Test)