# Create folders to group works in a package in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, package

Recently, I with my other 2 teammates started working with our very first java lab project. We are working on a single JAVA package named `com.SRPS` . Now as everyone of us is doing different parts of the project (e.g: Database, GUI, Java other coding etc), we want keep a separate folders inside this same package, so that we can distinguish our tasks and keep track individually Like:

```
        com.SRPS

        |-------- Misc Codes ( folder to store codes)

        |-------- GUI (Java Swing codes goes here)

        |--------- DB ( .sql files in this folder)
```

In intelliJ IDEA how to do it so that we can still work on the same package?
Apologies for my noob type question. But any help is gladly accepted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to work on the same package. It would be better to put different types of code into different sub-packages. If you create folders in com.SRPS its basically same as creating sub-packages.

Comment: You can create another package inside your package. Java won't stop you from doing that.

Comment: Take a look at [Create new package in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188773/create-new-package-in-intellij)